# How to download the uploaded file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file

I want to make a function to download the uploaded file in storage but it always display an error code : The file "D:\xampp php 7.2.2\htdocs\siapKerja_laravel\public\files/22" does not exist

```
public function show($idFile)
 { 
    $file = public_path(). "/files/";
    return Response()->download($file.$idFile);$
 } 

Route::get('/verifikasi/pkwt/download/{id}', 'FileController@show')->name('downloadFile');
```

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: mention your question,not the requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full url of the file.

Try to add the file extension:

`$extension = ".png" // or whatever type file is`

`return Response()->download($file.$idFile.$extension);`

When saving the file you can also get the extension when storing it:

```
$extension = $request->file('file')->extension();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you. I uploaded file in "files" folder, not in storage folder. you just make your change according to that.set your content_types according to your 
uploaded file.

my controller code is

```
public function  openPdf(Request $request,$docFile)
{   

    $file='/var/www/html/laravelQuiz/public/files/'.$docFile;
     $extension = explode(".",$docFile);

     foreach($extension as $extensions){
        if($extensions == 'pdf'){
           $content_types =  'application/pdf';
        }elseif($extensions == 'doc'){
           $content_types =  'application/msword';
        }elseif($extensions == 'txt'){
            $content_types =   'application/octet-stream';
        }elseif($extensions == 'docx'){
            $content_types =     'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
        }elseif($extensions == 'ppt'){
            $content_types = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
        }elseif($extensions == 'odt'){
            $content_types = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
        }elseif($extensions == 'txt'){
            $content_types = 'text/plain';
        }
     }
     $content = file_get_contents($file);               
     return Response::make($content, 200, array('content-type'=>$content_types));

}
```

Comment: shraddha `public_path()` will give the path till `'/var/www/html/laravelQuiz/public/`